# What does recontruction of Van's body mean?

Tags: gunxsword

During the testing phase of **Dann of Thursday** with **Van**, **Gadved** said, "Your body is not compatible, so your body need reconstruction".

After **The Claw** attacked Van and **Helena**, she ask Gadved to reconstruct Van's body, so that he can use Dann at full potential.

What do they mean by "reconstruction"?

Below is a screenshot from episode 12, where Van is asking Gadved to reconstruct him after The Claw's attack.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there has not been any information about what reconstruction means, but **Dann of Thursday** has the ability to regenerate.

> [It is seen that this reconstruction process is what gives them their regenerative capabilities.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_Sword#Armor)

So the main reason to reconstruct is to make **Van** body feasible to use Dann's regenerative capability.